# Access Control:Database issue showing in fortify scan

Tags: c#, .net, fortify

Here is the code:

```
public int Number
{
    get { return this._number; }
    set { this._number = value; }
}
```

The `value` is showing as Access Control:Database after fortify scan of the code. How can I remove this issue? Or is there any other way to protect the value?

(I have tried with setting the private and protect keywords for `public number` but it is not working)

Comment: Can't do sqli with an int. Are you sure you're looking at the correct warning?

Comment: Indeed, sql injection with an int does not seem possible -- however Fortify is less than perfect, and will scream bloody murder at anything that forms an SQL query the 'wrong' way (i.e. string concatenation).  The poster has not provided a full source-to-sink analysis from Fortify so it is possible that there is more happening here, but if the source is claimed to be an int, very likely it is a false positive.

Answer (score 2):

Fortify is either simply wrong, or is being remarkably obtuse. The code shown is simply an integer property. Virtually no relationship to SQL injection *whatsoever*. Are you sure it isn't complaining about something like:

```
string sql = "blah blah ... " + obj.Number + " ... more blah";
```

This is now getting on the same page as SQL injection (although the harm you can do with an integer is usually rather limited, even if this is simply bad code). The SQLi-safe way of implementing that would be:

```
string sql = "blah blah ... @number ... more blah";
//...
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("number", obj.Number); // or similar
```

Comment: the value is being used in stored proecdure....it's just its directly being inserted from user to sql without any check or its taking input from untrusted source.....so that's why its showing it.

Comment: @UmeshMandal ".it's just its directly being inserted from user to sql without any check or its taking input from untrusted source." - what is doing that? the code shown in the question certainly isn't; if you're using a stored procedure, I would *expect* the value to be parameterised, with only the value being passed, but: there's nothing at all SQL or ADO.NET-related - and no ORM code etc - in the question, so... hard to be definitive. A property by itself has nothing to do with SQL injection.

Comment: I know i just showed you only part of a code but you can see any .NET code where the variables are parameterized for a stored procedure...

Comment: @UmeshMandal yes, I know what parameterized variables for a stored procedure look like (I'm more than familiar with ADO.NET code...) - that wasn't my question; my point is: you're showing a simple integer property and asking about SQL injection. There is no intersection whatsoever between those two things. If you want a useful answer to the question, you're really going to have to show code that actually illustrates the thing you're asking about. Right now... it really doesn't.

Comment: Part of the issue here is that Umesh may not fully understand how to use Fortify, the other part is that it is very likely to be a false positive (Fortify is known to have many false positives).  If you login to Fortify SSC (or Fortify on Demand), you can find a source-to-sink analysis showing the whole data flow path that is involved in the vulnerability.  Umesh, you have only shown one part of that flow.  Somewhere in that flow most likely the `Number` is getting inserted in an SQL statement in the wrong way.  Fortify will panic when this happens, but you can't really exploit int types.

Comment: Sorry guys...its an access control:database issue and in there it is showing Assignment to this._number is  marked as red in fotify scan.